# Leak memory "Malloc XXbytes" by Instruments. How to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments

My project doesn't use ARC and support iOS 4.3+, used Parse,Crashlytics framework.

I tested by Instruments about leak memory.

This is result. The problem is that all thing is in library system. Nothing is related to my code.

How can I fix them? Somebody help me!

**Click to see fullsize** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRrkQ.png
[image]

Comment: any difference between running in a simulator or on a device?

Answer (score 0):

You application started a system thread shown in Instruments. It is not clear how. The thread doesn't call your code directly. It is somehow related to private DataDetectorsUI.framework; that calls CFStringTokenizer... You do not create this thread directly, you ask iOS to do something. Can you guess what is that and what part of your code triggered spawning the thread?

What are trying to do? Is it possible that you do not close the task properly?

Comment: Yes, I know instrument just pointed to where leak memory was allocated. But I dont know what is function in my code which called the system allocator because instruments didn't show. As attached image. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`DDOperation` is a `NSOperation` subclass that is part of the Data Detection framework in iOS and OS X. I can't pinpoint your leak to a specific line either, but it appears like you are leaking something that is created indirectly when you use `NSDataDetector`. Check if you are retaining anything when using the block based enumerator but never releasing it.